# Apply font size to img alt property without affecting the image size

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to set the font size to the img **alt property** but it affects the image size.

I'm doing something like this in the css

```
---
HTML Code:
<img alt="Some Text" src="http://www.someimage.com/img/010.jpg">


CSS:
img[alt]{font-size:0.75em;}
---
```

Can anyone help me in applying of font-size for the alt property of image without affecting image size.

**Please note I don't want to use Javascript. Just pure CSS**

Comment: To my knowledge you can't affect that with CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `alt` property is a property of the image tag, it's not an element by itself. You can't style the `alt` property, in much the same way as you can't style the `src` property.

When you use `img[alt]` as a selector in CSS, you are not targeting the `alt` attribute of image tags, you are targeting *any* image tag that has an `alt` attribute. As you are setting the font size of the image tag, it will naturally also affect the image tag.

If you mean that you want to style the tooltip that some browsers show when you hover the image, you can't do that. The tooltip is an implementation detail in the browser, and there is nothing in HTML that says that the `alt` attribute should be used that way, so there is no means in HTML for controlling that feature.

The intention of the `alt` attribute is to have something to show to the user if it's not possible to show the image.

Comment: I'm actually displaying a list of products with its image and some details. Now if for some, if the images are not getting displayed, it takes the 16px default font size. So it hampers the entire layout.

Comment: @Anubhav Ranjan: In what way do you see that setting the font size affect the image size? When I try it, it has no effect on the image size at all.

Comment: @Guffa: If I set a font size say 0.75em or even in pixels, it affects the image dimension. If its not for you, then can you please share your css styling.

Comment: @Anubhav Ranjan: I just tested some styles like `font-size: 200px`, `font-size: 0.75em` and `font-size: 1px`, and the image displays the same for all settings.

Comment: @Guffa: Are you applying the font-size for the img tag or img[alt].

Comment: @Anubhav Ranjan: I have tried both. Both applies to the image tag, so it doesn't make any difference as long as the image has an `alt` attribute.

Comment: I think you are right. It doesn't allows us to modify the size. It uses the default font-size set by the browser. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

In my personal testing, setting a font-size attribute on an image had no effect on the image.

I was able to resize the alt text, though. At first I tried putting HTML inside the alt attribute, but it was displayed as plain text, not HTML. Then I wrapped the image containing the alt text in a span tag with a style, and that worked, because the image inherited the font-size from the span.

Here is an example:

```
<span style="font-size: 0.75em">
    <img alt="Some Text" src="http://www.someimage.com/img/010.jpg">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275737/how-to-style-the-string-of-an-alt-tag) regarding the alt attribute.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But, I want this to be applied for portals developed for mobiles. So because of that I cannot actually use the JS. If I use the img[alt] in css, it changes the font-size but it also affects the image size.

Comment: What is the restriction on js for mobile? Just want to avoid it?

Comment: its like the project requirement. Since we are targeting on all the mobiles, most of the mobiles don't support js. So have to completely avoid JS

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think it's only controllable from the user's display property settings and can't be modified through css.