# how give line-height to an img's alt text in CSS

Tags: css

i have given to all my img alt text a specific font-size, so that they can be more readable if the img doesn't get loaded. But still the line-height is still too much. i tried to decrease the line-height in the css code below, but it doesn't effect. i don't want any jQuery work-arounds. I prefere to fix it css only.

thank you.

```
img[alt]{
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

Comment: try to reduce the line-height of their container

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407849/apply-font-size-to-img-alt-property-without-affecting-the-image-size

Comment: thank you, it worked !!! :-) . Just for curiousness. Is it possible to give line-height to the img itself? because i want to set this css as a global on all images in the site, and that i don't have to manage their containers individually. and that some containers might have their own specific line-height.

Comment: thank you Sirjiskit for the link, but in this method you have to wrap an element around each img element. which might not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "font-size" attribute to that img tag or you can use img tag in span or div any container tag , it'll work

I've tried this one
and it works fine

```html
<span style="font-size: large;"><img alt="your text" src=""></span>
```

thanks :)

Comment: thank you Mihir Lathiya, but is there a way without giving the image a container?

Comment: <img style="font-size: large;" alt="your text" src=""> like this ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to reduce the line-height of image container (credits: @Temani Afif)

`<div style="line-height: 1"><img src="..." alt="Foo bar"></div>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<span style="font-size: 1.75em">
            <img alt="Some Text" src="http://www.someimage.com/img/010.jpg">
        </span>
```

Comment: thank you Sirjiskit, but is there a way without giving the image a container?