# asp net imagebutton alternate text multiline

Tags: text, asp-classic, imagebutton, .net, alternate

I would like to know is it possible to make alernate text multiline, not single line?
Thanks, Oak.

Comment: could you gice an example, don't know what you mean

Comment: As a default, the text is located in top left corner of image, and if it islonger than the width of an image, the rest of the text just dissapears. I qould like to know if it is possible to have the text in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on certain browsers you can control the attibutes like so but it will affect the style of the image itself also.

```
<style>
img[alt] { border: 1px solid #000;display: block;  }
</style>
```

On my FF this displays all the text wrapped

Comment: oh yeah and i found this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275737/how-to-style-the-string-of-an-alt-tag

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility

```
<img id="img1" width=50 src="foo.jpg" alt="come here" 
  onmouseover="this.style.display='block';this.alt='looo oooooooo oooooooooo oooooooooo oooooong'"
  onmouseout="this.style.display='inline';this.alt='come here'"
/>
```